# Cannot select more dropdowns with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape for car prices from this [website](https://www.autotrader.com/car-values/):

To get car prices, you should fill out the form and I have to choose from dropdowns using Selenium.
I am using this code to choose from dropdowns:

```
# Imports
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

year_dropdown = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
                       .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "j_id_3q-carInfoForm-year-selectOneMenu"))))
year_dropdown.select_by_value('2015')
```

But after I chose the year, it just keeps loading and never stops:
[image]

Any suggestions please?

Comment: it says no permission to access this server

Comment: Really? Was it this link: https://www.autotrader.com/car-values/

Comment: It is working fine for me

Comment: I couldn't visit it, too.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. I can log in just fine, what might be the issue?

Comment: I could visit it now.But it wouldn't happen *"keeps loading and never stops:"*.It works fine for me.(You need to wait for a moment though)

Comment: It is working fine without selenium webdriver. If I use selenium, it just does not go past the year

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple times and I could load it with selenium.

Comment: Can you share the code? Maybe I am doing smth wrong

Comment: The same with you. I just copied it from your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using a real chrome driver. I was using chromdriver-manager package and when I removed it and downloaded a real chrome driver, the issue was gone.